# SNS with file attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have SNS notification for a S3 bucket. I wanted to push that SNS notification with attachment

We have a S3 bucket namely like SDD-XXX-YYY. Once if any file is getting arrived in that bucket, we have configured SNS to receive email notification.

Now we need email notification with content of the file which we are receiving in S3 or as attachment in our email.

Example: We are receiving some "error.log" file S3, here we need to push the error.log in email or else content of error.log file.

Please help me to achieve it.

Do we need to write lambda here? or we can manage it in SNS itself?

Answer (score 2):

The SNS S3 notification will only give you information about the newly created object.

You can see the structure of the event in [Event Message Structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html).

If you want to send the file via email you will have to write this logic in a Lambda function: you will use the information from the event (bucket and key) to download the object and then send it via email.

This function could subscribe to SNS or directly to S3.

Comment: So to paste the content of error file in email also, we need to write lambda.. Right? @jogold

Comment: Ok. Its not exactly error file. Consider any file is getting uploaded in S3, i need the content of that file to be sent through email. Uploading files have some log or error information only. So it wont have much volume of data.

Comment: Yes, you will have to write a Lambda to download your file and send it via email, as explained in my answer.